# pagechange method doesn't work on android 2

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have set up a small mobile application and during tests I have stumbled upon a problem with older versions of mobile devices running Android version 2. Please note that iPhones, iPads and newer versions of Android, namely 4.xx display the pages well. The problem is as follows:

When page is called directly from the link:

```
<a href="#SSMain" data-icon="home" data-theme="e">Home</a>
```

it is properly displayed.

However, when there is a click handler on a link, like here:

```
$(document).on('click', '#lstAddrList li', function ()
    {
        var anchor = $(this).find('a');
        sessionStorage.SiteAddr = anchor.attr('id');
        changePage();
    });
```

the list line (in this case) stays selected and nothing happens. It is ONLY after the calling page is refreshed directly from the browser when the called page is displayed. I have a feeling that older Androids do not properly handle changePage() method.

Will you have some ideas?

Comment: Problem here is not an older version of Android, ok it is, but in smaller manner. You need to change your code. When you click on a listview you are triggering 2 changePage events. One on a a tab and second one programatically and that is bad. Remove href from a tag, put it in some custom attribute. And handle pageChange only programatically.

Comment: @Gajotres : I tried to remove href from the tag and use changePage('#PageName') but it doesn't work. I am not sure what kind of custom attribute I should put it and how to handle it later on. The piece of code for handling of the click was recommended for handling list item clicks and it works except for old Androids